# Printing Euler Path

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I am given an undirected graph and I need to print the euler path of this graph from vertex A to vertex B. My algorithm is this: Firstly I find all the edges which are bridges by using the Tarjan Algorithm. Then, starting from vertex A, from every vertex I choose one of his edges, trying not to burn bridges, that is if i can choose edges that are not bridges I choose them. However this solution gave me just 30/100 points of my problem. I found also a O((N+M)^2) solution that works fine but as N and M are very big I need something linear.

Here my code, do you have any suggestion? :

```
int N, M, A, B, c, dfs_low[MAX_N], dfs_num[MAX_N], dfs_parent[MAX_N],articulation_vertex[MAX_N];
int dfsNumberCounter = 1, dfsRoot, rootChildren;
vii g[MAX_N];

void articulationPointAndBridge(int u) {
  dfs_low[u] = dfs_num[u] = dfsNumberCounter++;     // dfs_low[u] <= dfs_num[u]
  for (int j = 0; j < (int)g[u].size(); j++) {
    ii v = g[u][j];
    if (dfs_num[v.first] == DFS_WHITE) {                          // a tree edge
      dfs_parent[v.first] = u;
      if (u == dfsRoot) rootChildren++;  // special case, count children of root
      articulationPointAndBridge(v.first);
      if (dfs_low[v.first] > dfs_num[u]){                           // for bridge
        g[u][j].second = 2;
        for(int i=0;i<g[v.first].size();i++)
            if(g[v.first][i].first == u && g[v.first][i].second){
                g[v.first][i].second = 2;
                break;
            }
       }
      dfs_low[u] = min(dfs_low[u], dfs_low[v.first]);       // update dfs_low[u]
    }
    else if (v.first != dfs_parent[u])       // a back edge and not direct cycle
      dfs_low[u] = min(dfs_low[u], dfs_num[v.first]);       // update dfs_low[u]
} }

void EulPath(int u){ 
    int idx = -1;
    for(int i=0;i<g[u].size();i++)
        if(g[u][i].second == 1){
            idx = i;
            break;
        }

    if(idx == -1)
        for(int j=0;j<g[u].size();j++)
            if(g[u][j].second){
                idx = j;
                break;
            }
    if(idx != -1){
        int v = g[u][idx].first;
        out<<u+1<<" "<<v+1<<endl;
        g[u][idx].second=0;
        for(int j=0;j<g[v].size();j++)
            if(g[v][j].first == u && g[v][j].second){
                g[v][j].second = 0;
                break;
            }
        EulPath(v);
    }

}





int main() {
    //in = fopen("input.txt","r"); out = fopen("output.txt","w");
    in.open("input.txt"); out.open("output.txt");

    //fscanf(in, "%d %d %d %d" , &N, &M, &A, &B);
    in>>N>>M>>A>>B;
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        int t,t2;
        //fscanf(in, "%d %d", &t, &t2);
        in>>t>>t2; t--; t2--;
        g[t].pb(ii(t2,1));
        g[t2].pb(ii(t,1));
    }
    articulationPointAndBridge(A-1);
    /*for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<g[i].size();j++)
            cout << i <<" "<<g[i][j].first<<" "<<g[i][j].second<<endl;
            cin>>N;*/
    EulPath(A-1);

    in.close(); out.close();
    //fclose(in); fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your question is off-topic. This is because you are asking for 'something better', which implies that you are wanting someone to re-write your code.

Comment: Which project euler problem is this? Or is this from ioi? But isn't it unlikely to be from both?

Comment: @zyboxinternational: *Every* question on SO in which the asker has bothered to show that they've done some work themselves can be framed as wanting someone to re-write your code.  This question is as on-topic as it gets.

Comment: @zyboxinternational : I don't want someone to rewrite my code, I need just someone that can explain me where I am wrong. This is the problem of printing euler path.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Everybody else seems to think it's off-topic, since the question has been put on hold for being off-topic.

Comment: @zyboxinternational: Yes they do, and that's not something I totally disregard, but I think they're wrong.  Do you disagree with the first sentence in my previous comment?  If so, I'd be interested in an example or two of a question that shows effort on the part of the OP but which you think cannot be framed in that way.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I'm talking about *directly* asking to re-write code. Almost all good questions on SO have some code-rewriting.

Comment: @zyboxinternational: I didn't interpret the question as emacoder asking us to rewrite the code, and in a comment he makes that clear.  He summarised his current approach at the top; I think the code was just added to give detail, in case that was helpful (anticipating the common first request of "Please show us exactly what you're currently doing").

Answer (score 2):

I would consider implementing Hierholzer's algorithm.  (See, for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Hierholzer.27s_algorithm).  No need to pre-detect bridges.